# Using a conversion function to make something an instance of a type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Let's say I have:

```
data MyType
myToDouble :: MyType -> Double
```

Let's say I want MyType to be an instance of Num or Real or something that Double is already an instance of.

Is there a simple way to accomplish that without having to manually writing out all the methods in Num/Real for it?

So... is there some way of just saying:

```
instance Real MyType by way of myToDouble
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely not; `Real` depends on `Num`, and `Num` has methods which return `a` (or more accurately, are covariant in `a`).  How are you going to implement:

```
(+) :: MyType -> MyType -> MyType
```

given just `MyType` and `myToDouble`?

Now maybe you already have all the other instances and are just wondering about `Real`.   Well, the only method `Real` has is of its own `toRational`, so:

```
instance Real MyType where
    toRational = toRational . myToDouble
```

As for your more general question: unfortunately not.  If you have a class whose methods are all contravariant (only take as arguments) in the type variable, then you should be able to automatically define a typeclass on a projection like this.  But Haskell has no mechanism to do so.  (You could write one yourself using Template Haskell).

You *can* "forward" a newtype's instances to its underlying type using `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.  Eg.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype MyType = MyType Double
    deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Num,Real)
```

But you can't use any old isomorphism.  It's a shame.